# Rendering only missing frames on animation

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I'm rendering an animation in blender as image files and I wanted to render some parts of it first, just so I can see these particular parts first.
Also, some parts of the animation, I rendered jumping a few frames (with the frames step config set to 3).

**Is there a way to easily render only the missing frames?** Maybe by making blender read the image files names and identifying the missing ones.

And I wanted to know aswell if there is a way to insert the rendered frames in the video editor but with the "right position". For example, I rendered frames 1, 3 and 5. As I insert it on the editor, the frames 2 and 4 would be blank, but my video would still have 5 frames.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set the frame range from and to any frames you like in the timeline, both from the 3D window or the VSE.  Just render each lot out as single (png?) frames into a special folder which you nominate at the right under the "Render" properties.  Each render session can go into that same folder so long as the frames don't overlap.  If any do, the new ones will overwrite what was there before. Each file is named by it's frame number.  Once done you should be able to view the file sequences by importing them (SH-A) into the Vide editor. (VSE)

Comment: Just leave everything the way you have it now, the same frame range and paths. In the Finder or Explorer or whatever you use to navigate through your files, just delete the frames you want to get rid of. Then in the output options of blender **disable** the option to **overwrite** and hit Ctrl+F12. Existing frames will be ignored only the missing ones will get rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Render Settings under [Output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html#output-panel) you will find the overwrite option will do what you want.

> Overwrite - Overwrite existing files when rendering.

What that means is that when overwrite is disabled and blender goes to render frame 12 and the file for frame 12 already exists it will not render that frame and go onto the next one.

For the VSE, if a bad (or empty) file exists for a frame when you add the image sequence to the VSE it will read the updated file for the bad frame/s once you have rendered them.